# External hard drive with read-only switch?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-encryption, read-only

I am planning to get myself an external HDD. Is there any offering that you may be aware of with an option to open the contents in a default read-only mode (may be firmware based or physical switch), allowing write operations only after authenticating (may be like a password or physical switch), without having to install any driver/software in each computer I plug this into? Does encrypting give me the same facility? This is because I don't want to regret after plugging my HDD to an unknown PC possibly infected when I just want some data copied from disk to that PC. Thanks!

Comment: The floppy disks used to have a physical switch/lock if you remember!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick google search has lead me to this:

http://www.digitalintelligence.com/cart/ComputerForensicsProducts/3.5-Inch-USB3-Hard-Drive-Enclosure-WRITE-BLOCKER.html

It is a Hardware Write Blocker http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Write_Blockers